# Saving JSON to Sqlite and displaying it

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I have successfully accessed the data from an external datbase using JSONObject, but my problem is that I am going to save it to the sqlite database. By the time that I retrieve the data I only got the last row from sqlite. The main issue is getting the data from sqlite not JSON, maybe I got wrong in assigning or retrieving.. noobness state here..thanks

CODE BEFORE ADDING THE SQLITE CODE:

```
                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
```

Adding to SQlite:

```
           { // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

           // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

            //individually get each arrays
            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

             //code to add each retrieved data from JSONArray to Sqlite
             db.addContact(new Menu(id.toString(), name.toString()));

        }
         // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Menu> contacts = db.getAllContacts(); 

        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (Menu cn : contacts) {

                // Writing Contacts to log

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(TAG_PID, cn.getID().toString());
        map.put(TAG_NAME,cn.getName().toString());

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        productsList.add(map);
        }
```

Another Part of the Program:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                Main_Activity.this, productsList,
                                R.layout.activity_view_products, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                        TAG_NAME},
                                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Another Code:

```
// Adding new contact
void addContact(Menu contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, contact.getID()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
  // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Menu> getAllContacts() {
    List<Menu> contactList = new ArrayList<Menu>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Menu contact = new Menu();
            contact.setID((cursor.getString(0).toString()));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1).toString());

            Log.d("Menu: ", contact.getID().toString());

            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of this

```
map.put(TAG_PID, cn.getID().toString()); // TAG_PID is the same for all entry id, hence, overrideen
map.put(TAG_NAME,cn.getName().toString()); // TAG_NAME is the same for all entry name, hence, overrideen    
// adding HashList to ArrayList
productsList.add(map);
```

You are inserting all the records in the map with the same `PID` and `NAME` keys. Hence, each record keeps getting overridden every time a new entry is added to the map. Hence, you can see only the last record in the map.

Instead, keep your `PID` as the key and `NAME` as the value(assuming ID is unique), if not you can simply use the ArrayList of your objects as such, instead of converting it to a Map.

Instead of this you need to do this:-

```
map.put(cn.getID().toString(), cn.getName().toString());

// adding HashList to ArrayList
productsList.add(map);
```

**Update:-**
After seeing your requirement, I think this is what you need to do.

```
for (Menu cn : contacts) {

    // creating new HashMap - for every Menu
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); // this should be within the for loop.

    // Writing Contacts to log
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(TAG_PID, cn.getID().toString());
    map.put(TAG_NAME, cn.getName().toString());

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    productsList.add(map);
}
```

Comment: thanks @R.J for the fast resp. Can you include a bit of explanation for the new code [ map.put(cn.getID().toString(), cn.getName().toString()); ]. ^^

Comment: Yeah, or create a real class instead of a HashMap.

Comment: I tried the code, I got the correct # of lines in the listView which is correct but they are empty, before I got the same lines occupied by the last row.

Comment: @lordzden - The new code will put entries in the HashMap where the key will be the `id` and `value` will be the name. Since, `key` must be unique in your case, it keeps overriding the previous values. Hoping that your `id` in `Menu` object is unique, I've suggested you to use that as the `key` in the map.

Comment: Since the insertion logic in the MAP has changed, your retrieval logic also needs to change accordingly. Do show where and how you use the map, so that I can suggest necessary changes there also.

Comment: @lordzden- Check the update in my answer. You need to create a new map for each `Menu` object, as each `map` entry in the list, will constitute a row.

Comment: I added more codes above I hope you'll find something significant. Trying the updated answer....

Comment: @R.J, vien danke! It's working now!!. But the next problem every time I run the application, each of the saved menu in sqlite dobles in #. What Should I do? ^^